Android bluetooth read/write crashes when job cancelled
I am writing an Android App that connects to an OBD2 bluetooth device and reads ECU data from a vehicle. I create a bluetooth socket and open an input and output stream on the socket. I call a startPolling() function to loop and read data from the OBD2 device every 1ms which launces as a GlobalScope.launch and i keep a reference to the job that is returned.
All works well but when the user navigates to a different activity i override onPause() and in that function i call job.cancel() and then a function resetConnection() that closes the socket. The App crashes as it tries to read/write on the socket after it has been closed.
The function i call to start polling the ECU device:
private fun startPollingData() {
        job = GlobalScope.launch {
        while (isActive) {
            yield()
            if (m_bluetoothSocket?.isConnected == true) {
                val engineRPMCommand = RPMCommand()
                engineRPMCommand.run(m_inputStream, m_outputStream)
                val speedCommand = SpeedCommand()
                speedCommand.run(m_inputStream, m_outputStream)
                val fuelLevelCommand = FuelLevelCommand()
                fuelLevelCommand.run(m_inputStream, m_outputStream)
                val fuelConsumptionCommand = ConsumptionRateCommand()
                fuelConsumptionCommand.run(m_inputStream, m_outputStream)

                runOnUiThread {
                    rthViewModel.updateRPMData(engineRPMCommand.rpm)
                    rthViewModel.updateSpeedData(speedCommand.imperialSpeed)
                    rthViewModel.updateFuelLevelDataData(fuelLevelCommand.fuelLevel)
                    rthViewModel.updateFuelConsumptionDataData(fuelConsumptionCommand.litersPerHour)
                }
                delay(1)
            }
        }
    }
}

when the user navigates away i have:
override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        job?.cancel()
        resetConnection()
    }


The resetConnection() function is closing the socket before the job has fully cancelled:
private fun resetConnection() {
            Log.d("RTA","Resetting connection")
        if (m_bluetoothSocket != null) {
            try {
                m_inputStream?.close()
                m_inputStream = null
                m_outputStream?.close()
                m_outputStream = null
                m_bluetoothSocket?.close()
                m_bluetoothSocket = null
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("RTA","Cannot close socket in reset function")
            }
            m_bluetoothSocket = null
        }
    }

The logcat error is
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void         java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    at com.github.pires.obd.commands.ObdCommand.sendCommand(ObdCommand.java:107)
                                                                                                    at com.github.pires.obd.commands.ObdCommand.run(ObdCommand.java:87)
                                                                                                    at uk.co.awenmedia.obd2b.RealtimeHomeActivity$startPollingData$1.invokeSuspend(RealtimeHomeActivity.kt:215)

